# cannot install texStudio in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I want to install texstudio in terminal by using this command: 'sudo apt-get install texstudio'
but get this error:

> 'The following packages have unmet dependencies:  texstudio : Depends:
>   libpoppler-qt5-1 (>= 0.34.0) but it is not installable
>                Recommends: latex-beamer but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'

I change the default settings of softwares & updates in ubuntu which looks like this:

[image]

is there anyway to fixed it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and then trying again

Comment: I forgot to tell that I'd changed my sofwares & updates

Comment: enable community-maintained free (universe) and try again

Comment: same error message? did  you do apt-get update and upgrade?

Comment: yes I did, in 'sudo apt-get update', I get these errors:

Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gummi/gummi/ubuntu bionic Release              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

before trying texstudio, I'd tried gummi and texlive which both of them gave same error.